# Twilio SMS: Is there a way to recognize status updates from SMS generated with SMS API vs TwiML <message/> responses?

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-twiml

My service is sending SMS to users in two different ways:
The main one is the SMS API, my service sends a request to Twilio with all the SMS data, and get the SMS id in the response. With that id it waits for the sms status updates to check if the text was delivered.
But there is another way, as a response to a user sending a text to my service, using a TwiML `<message>` in the Response. In this case, I send back a SMS to the user, but there is no SMS id to check for status updates (because the service sends the text in the response, not in the request).
So in this scenario, there are status updates from SMS ids that the service can not recognize.

My question is: is there a way to get the SMS id from TwiML `<message>`s? Or be able to recognise which status updates come from TwiML messages?
Or my only way to do this is to always call the SMS API and do not return a text using TwiML for this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The way to get an SID from replying to a message using `<Message>` is to wait for the status callback webhook. Of course, as you say here, when you reply that way you don't store the details of the message in your system. What you could do is wait for the first status callback webhook and if you find a message SID that you don't already have in your system, [use the REST API to look up that message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource), save the details and be prepared for further status callbacks.

Alternatively, there is nothing wrong with using the REST API to send the message instead of `<Message>` and just returning an empty `<Response>` to an incoming webhook.